# Grails, Thread.start { ... } not working from BootStrap.groovy

Tags: grails, groovy

I am running this code in BootStrap.groovy :

```
        if (Core.isDevelopment()) {
                File file = Core.getWebappFile("${App.files.root}App/styles/empty.less");

                if (file && file.exists() ) {

                        Core.Log.println('File exists')

                        def thread = Thread.start {
                                Core.Log.println('Thread append')

                                file << ' ';

                                sleep( App.lessRefresh );
                        }

                }
        }
```

It runs once, that is 'File exists' is printed once, and 'Thread append' once only.

I understand this might have to do with threads being forbidden in a Java EE container, but is this what the problem is?

How can I create a thread or achieve what I am after in a different way? Preferably without installing a separate plugin!

Comment: If it prints "Thread append", it's working... What else did you expect?

Comment: It is printing it once only. Should it not print every 700 ms (App.lessRefresh = 700 ) ?

Comment: Not without a loop... As you have it, it will print, sleep, then finish

Comment: hmm ... i figured that that was taken care of ... so while ( true ) is safe usage?

Comment: Yeah, but you're probably better using a [ScheduledExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) or the quartz plugin to schedule a task to run every n millis